# Normalizing a strongly bimodal distribution

Tags: distributions, survival, bimodal

I am working with measurements of "spring vigor" of a perennial plant measured on a 0-20 scale.  It is meant to screen for winter damage.  In this experiment, there are many individuals who are entirely immune (large peak at 20) and many dead individuals (peak at 0).  I could evaluate this as logistic and lose a relatively small amount of information, but wonder if there is another solution.  I could assume that the ability to survive winter is, in reality, normal distribution and therefore could determine the population mean for spring vigor.  The more complex question is how to determine the variance around the mean assuming a normal distribution.  Somehow using the number of individuals between the two peaks should provide an estimate of variance, I'm just not savvy enough to figure it out.

UPDATE: To clarify, because of previous experiments and observations, I can conclude that the underlying trait in these plants is not bimodal.  The bimodal distribution of observations is caused by all individuals above 0 and below 20 to be ranked as the same value.  To put it simply, all dead plants look the same regardless if they just barely died or are extremely winter susceptible.  Same goes for higly winter resistant plants.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The assumption that vigor is normally distributed appears to be soundly disproved by the data - you don't need a normality test to know that data is not normal. Why would you want to fit a distribution that will not describe your data under *any* parameterization? Calculating the mean and variance of this population is straightforward, but there's no reason to expect that those are sufficient statistics to describe the distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!   This is a case where I am confident that the trait that I am interested in is normally distributed (or close to it).  However, my observation method is causing distribution issues.  For example, if a plant dies due to winter stress, it's measurement is zero.  We do not know how extreme it's true survival ability is because you can't get a measurement worse than completely dead (0).  I'll try clarifying the post.

Comment: Hm, I'm not convinced the underlying variable is normal, since you get an increase in frequency near the tails even *before* you hit the cutoff, at values like 1 and 18. There doesn't seem to be any central tendency in this data, and I can't think of any way to "distribute" the counts at 0 and 20 further to the left or right (beyond the limits of your observable values) that would make this look normal. The best I could come up with is to have  mean of slightly below 0, but then you should see values near 20 as far less likely than values near 0, although they are not.

Comment: To me, it looks like you have two distinct populations of plants, one that's generally winter-susceptible and one that's not, and the overall distribution you're seeing is a combination of two different populations that each have their own normal distribution of spring vigor. A Gaussian mixture model might be a way to approach this, since I don't see a good way to fit a single normal distribution to this data, even if you take into account the limited observable range. Perhaps you have two subspecies or lineages of plants?

Comment: That is a very good idea and is something to watch out for, but it's unlikely to be true in this case.  These observations are from a nursery of progeny from a small number of parents, so the trait values should be well mixed.  We know from prior experients that if I intercrossed all my strong survivors (20s), I would again get strong bimodal distribution like this, but with the right side peak would get slightly larger because of the selection.

Comment: If the trait you are interested in is normally distributed then the measure you used doesn't measure the trait you are interested in. You might, for example, look at how long the plant survived, or what the growth of the plant was at multiple points during the winter, or something else.